# Prolog retract more then one fact and then assert

Tags: prolog

```
:- dynamic flat/3.
addr('Nollendorfstr',5).
addr('Nollendorfstr',14).
addr('Nollendorfstr',18).
addr('Maxplanckstr',2).

flat([16,12,4],400.35, addr('Nollendorfstr',14)).
flat([14,13,4],380.00, addr('Nollendorfstr',18)).
flat([20,18,4,5],650.80, addr('Nollendorfstr',5)).
flat([9,17,19,20],870.70, addr('Maxplanckstr',2)).
```

We have for each flat three arguments. So `flat(array of rooms, price, address)`.

```
changeprice(Street):-
   retract(flat(Rooms,Price,addr(Street,Num))),
   Newprice is Price - (Price / 10),                         
   asserta(flat(Rooms,Newprice,addr(Street,Num))).
```

I'd like to change the price for all flats which are in this street.

so when I put there `changeprice('Nollendorfstr').` 
It will just change one of them.
How can I change all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either a failure-driven loop (which gets its name from the use of explicit failure after processing an item to backtrack into processing the next item):

```
changeprice(Street) :-
    retract(flat(Rooms,Price,addr(Street,Num))),
    Newprice is Price - (Price / 10),                      
    asserta(flat(Rooms,Newprice,addr(Street,Num))),
    fail.
changeprice(_).
```

Or the de facto standard `forall/2` meta-predicate (where the first argument can be interpreted as a *generator* of candidate solutions that are verified by the second argument, the *test* part):

```
changeprice(Street) :-
    forall(
        retract(flat(Rooms,Price,addr(Street,Num))),
        (   Newprice is Price - (Price / 10),                      
            asserta(flat(Rooms,Newprice,addr(Street,Num)))
        )
    ).
```

In this particular case, both solutions are equivalent. But note that failure-driven loops and `forall/2` calls have different semantics. A failure-driven loop can mask an unexpected failure. But a `forall/2` call will fail instead of succeeding if the second argument fails.